# DDPG doesn't converge for MountainCarContinuous-v0 gym environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python, policy-gradients, ddpg, gym

I am trying to implement Deep Deterministic policy gradient algorithm by referring to the paper *Continuous Control using Deep Reinforcement Learning* on the MountainCarContinuous-v0 gym environment. I am using 2 hidden Linear layers of size 32 for both the actor and the critic networks with ReLU activations and a Tanh activation for the output layer of the actor network. However, for some reason, algorithm doesn't seem to converge for some reason. I tried tuning the hyperparameters to no success.

- Code

```
import copy
import random
from collections import deque, namedtuple

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

"""
Hyperparameters:

actor_layer_sizes
critic_layer_sizes
max_buffer_size
polyak_constant
max_time_steps
max_episodes
actor_lr
critic_lr
GAMMA
update_after
batch_size
"""

device = torch.device("cpu")
dtype = torch.double

Transition = namedtuple(
    "Transition", ("state", "action", "reward", "next_state", "done")
)


class agent:
    def __init__(
        self,
        env,
        actor_layer_sizes=[32, 32],
        critic_layer_sizes=[32, 32],
        max_buffer_size=2500,
    ):
        self.env = env
        (
            self.actor,
            self.critic,
            self.target_actor,
            self.target_critic,
        ) = self.make_models(actor_layer_sizes, critic_layer_sizes)
        self.replay_buffer = deque(maxlen=max_buffer_size)
        self.max_buffer_size = max_buffer_size

    def make_models(self, actor_layer_sizes, critic_layer_sizes):
        actor = (
            nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(
                    self.env.observation_space.shape[0],
                    actor_layer_sizes[0],
                ),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(actor_layer_sizes[0], actor_layer_sizes[1]),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(
                    actor_layer_sizes[1], self.env.action_space.shape[0]
                ), nn.Tanh()
            )
            .to(device)
            .to(dtype)
        )

        critic = (
            nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(
                    self.env.observation_space.shape[0]
                    + self.env.action_space.shape[0],
                    critic_layer_sizes[0],
                ),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(critic_layer_sizes[0], critic_layer_sizes[1]),
                nn.ReLU(),
                nn.Linear(critic_layer_sizes[1], 1),
            )
            .to(device)
            .to(dtype)
        )

        target_actor = copy.deepcopy(actor)    # Create a target actor network

        target_critic = copy.deepcopy(critic)   # Create a target critic network

        return actor, critic, target_actor, target_critic

    def select_action(self, state, noise_factor):         # Selects an action in exploratory manner
      with torch.no_grad():
        noisy_action = self.actor(state) + noise_factor * torch.randn(size = self.env.action_space.shape, device=device, dtype=dtype)
        action = torch.clamp(noisy_action, self.env.action_space.low[0], self.env.action_space.high[0])

        return action

    def store_transition(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):             # Stores the transition to the replay buffer with a default maximum capacity of 2500
        if len(self.replay_buffer) < self.max_buffer_size:
            self.replay_buffer.append(
                Transition(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
            )
        else:
            self.replay_buffer.popleft()
            self.replay_buffer.append(
                Transition(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
            )

    def sample_batch(self, batch_size=128):                                            # Samples a random batch of transitions for training
      return Transition(
            *[torch.cat(i) for i in [*zip(*random.sample(self.replay_buffer, min(len(self.replay_buffer), batch_size)))]]
        )


    def train(
        self,
        GAMMA=0.99,
        actor_lr=0.001,
        critic_lr=0.001,
        polyak_constant=0.99,
        max_time_steps=5000,
        max_episodes=200,
        update_after=1,
        batch_size=128,
        noise_factor=0.2,
    ):
        
        self.train_rewards_list = []
        actor_optimizer = optim.Adam(self.actor.parameters(), lr=actor_lr)
        critic_optimizer = optim.Adam(
            self.critic.parameters(), lr=critic_lr
        )
        print("Starting Training:\n")
        for e in range(max_episodes):
            state = self.env.reset()
            state = torch.tensor(state, device=device, dtype=dtype).unsqueeze(0)
            episode_reward = 0
            for t in range(max_time_steps):
                #self.env.render()
                action = self.select_action(state, noise_factor)               
                next_state, reward, done, _ = self.env.step(action[0])         # Sample a transition
                episode_reward += reward

                next_state = torch.tensor(next_state, device=device, dtype=dtype).unsqueeze(0)
                reward = torch.tensor(
                    [reward], device=device, dtype=dtype
                ).unsqueeze(0)
                done = torch.tensor(
                    [done], device=device, dtype=dtype
                ).unsqueeze(0)

                self.store_transition(                               
                    state, action, reward, next_state, done
                )                # Store the transition in the replay buffer

                state = next_state
                
                sample_batch = self.sample_batch(128)

                with torch.no_grad():                 # Determine the target for the critic to train on
                  target = sample_batch.reward + (1 - sample_batch.done) * GAMMA * self.target_critic(torch.cat((sample_batch.next_state, self.target_actor(sample_batch.next_state)), dim=1))
                
                # Train the critic on the sampled batch
                critic_loss = nn.MSELoss()(
                    target,
                    self.critic(
                        torch.cat(
                            (sample_batch.state, sample_batch.action), dim=1
                        )
                    ),
                )

                critic_optimizer.zero_grad()
                critic_loss.backward()
                critic_optimizer.step()

                actor_loss = -1 * torch.mean(
                  self.critic(torch.cat((sample_batch.state, self.actor(sample_batch.state)), dim=1))
                  )

                #Train the actor  
                actor_optimizer.zero_grad()
                actor_loss.backward()
                actor_optimizer.step()
                

                #if (((t + 1) % update_after) == 0):
                for actor_param, target_actor_param in zip(self.actor.parameters(), self.target_actor.parameters()):
                  target_actor_param.data = polyak_constant * actor_param.data + (1 - polyak_constant) * target_actor_param.data
                  
                for critic_param, target_critic_param in zip(self.critic.parameters(), self.target_critic.parameters()):
                  target_critic_param.data = polyak_constant * critic_param.data + (1 - polyak_constant) * target_critic_param.data

                if done:
                    print(
                        "Completed episode {}/{}".format(
                            e + 1, max_episodes
                        )
                    )
                    break

            self.train_rewards_list.append(episode_reward)

        self.env.close()
        print(self.train_rewards_list)

    def plot(self, plot_type):
        if (plot_type == "train"):
            plt.plot(self.train_rewards_list)
            plt.show()
        elif (plot_type == "test"):
            plt.plot(self.test_rewards_list)
            plt.show()
        else:
            print("\nInvalid plot type")
```

- Train code snippet

```
import gym

env = gym.make("MountainCarContinuous-v0")

myagent = agent(env)
myagent.train(max_episodes=150)
myagent.plot("train")
```

The figure below shows the plot for episode reward vs episode number:

[image]

Comment: have you tried tuning the reward function? I've never played with the continuous case but I recall for the discrete action case I had to modify the reward function as otherwise the feedback is too sparse.

Comment: try modifying it so the reward is based on how far from the top of the hill the vehicle is.

Comment: The reward function is defined in the gym environment itself right? I am not sure how to modify it. Besides I have seen several implementation which converge without any such modifications

Comment: when you store the reward just have another line after that defining your own reward. for it to work without any modification you need a lot more compute power and memory because as I mentioned your rewards are sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change the actions selection function for this and tune some hyper-parameters. Here's what I did to make it converge:

- Sampled the noise from a standard normal distribution instead of sampling randomly.
- Changed the polyak constant (tau) from 0.99 to 0.001 (I didn't have an idea of what it should be, so I had just set it randomly in the first try)
- Changed the hidden layer sizes of the critic network to [64, 64].
- Removed the ReLU activation after the second layer in the critic network. Earlier the layer were stacked as (Linear, ReLU, Linear, ReLU, Linear). I changed it to (Linear, ReLU, Linear, Linear).
- Changed max buffer size to 1000000
- Changed the size of the batch_size to be sampled from 128 to 64

This is the plot that I get now after training it for 75 episodes :

[image]

Comment: Did you use max_time_steps = 5000? Cause I believe that the standard task has 200 and as such you wouldn't find a solution.